# Set HasMany array during record creation

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i am trying to set a has many array of a object i am creating

```
  var template = {
    title:this.get('model').get('title'),
  }
  template = this.store.createRecord('template', template);
  template.get('sections').pushObjects(this.get('model').get('sections').map(function(x){return x}));
```

this.get('model').get('sections') is the same object as template.sections

but i keep getting the following error: Assertion Failed: The content property of DS.PromiseArray should be set before modifying it

I don't want to save the object on the server before I set the sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if `sections` is empty it's still a promise (since it's async), so you'll still want to `then(...)` it before you attempt to use it.

```
var otherSections = this.get('model.sections').toArray();
template.get('sections').then(function(sections){
   sections.pushObjects(otherSections);
})
```

Comment: it should be noted that you must call the save method in the then method

Comment: Yes, that's another side effect of using the async relationships (the save, reload, revert all live on the result of the promise, not the promise)